# Set rowsource on form load (Access, SQL)

Tags: sql, forms, ms-access, vba

I try to set the rowsource of a listbox on form load but I can't get it to work. I have 3 different forms which can load another form via a button. This single form display some records based on the "ID_Projekttyp" which comes from the 3 main forms. The "ID_Projekttyp" will be provided by openargs.

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
varSplitString = Split(Me.OpenArgs, "|")
TempVar = CInt(varSplitString(1))
MsgBox TempVar
strSQL = " SELECT tbl_Projektphasen.Bezeichnung, tbl_Projekttypen.ID_Projekttypen " & _
" FROM tbl_Projektphasen INNER JOIN tbl_Projekttypen ON tbl_Projektphasen.ID_Projektphasen = tbl_Projekttypen.moeglicheProjektphasen.Value " & _
" WHERE (((tbl_Projekttypen.ID_Projekttypen)=" & TempVar
Me.Phasenbezeichnung.RowSource = strSQL
Me.Phasenbezeichnung.Requery
End Sub
```

The messagebox returns 3 (as example which is working so the error must be inside the sql statement but I can't find it.

Anyone can help?

Comment: Remove the parentheses from the WHERE clause. moeglicheProjektphasen is a multi-value field?

Comment: Note that if you would actually use a `TempVar` instead of a variable named `TempVar`, you could just refer to TempVars in queries by using `TempVars!MyTempVar`, thus removing the need to dynamically change your `RowSource` on load. If you also set the `TempVar` in the code opening your form, instead of passing it to `OpenArgs` and then setting it in the form you're opening, the entire `Form_Load` action would be unnecessary.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth   Your advice may work nicely in many scenarios, but it is possible to reuse forms in Access--have the same form class create and open multiple forms concurrently--so using some globally accessible variable with a reference embedded in the Row Source query may not work in all situations.  OpenArgs has always annoyed me--that it's not more flexible (like an array of Variants), but at least passing arguments directly to a newly created/opened form follows best practices rather than once again using globally accessible variables set elsewhere and later retrieved--tastes bad.

Comment: @June7
Thank you, you're right! Yeah it is. Have to create a temporary Access database for approx. 2-3 years before we can finally launch a professional software across all the departments (engineering, sales, production). I know it's not the best behaviour to use a multi-value field but it seems to work best here :)

Comment: Do you understand that multi-value field is unique to Access? If you plan to migrate data to another platform in 2-3 years this will cause complications.

Comment: Yeah I know. This is just a temporary solution. We are about to change the whole data management and this Access database will be deleted :) but anyway thanks for the heads up :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove all parentheses in where clause to make it clear (you have 3 before where and one after which is not correct)

```
" WHERE tbl_Projekttypen.ID_Projekttypen=" & TempVar
```